# How do i change parameter to run a particular story file in jenkins for jbehave

Tags: jenkins, bdd, jbehave

I have stories file in following order

```java
@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {
    return new StoryFinder()
            //.findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile(), asList("**/AAA.story"), null);
            //.findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile(), asList("**/BBB.story"), null);
}
```

I am able to run the story locally without any issue but i want to run a particular story from Jenkins. Do i need to add a property in POM file. If so how would the property name be set. Any one who has faced similar case.
Thanks

Comment: you should parametrize your configuration (provide an ability to set values not from source code), test it locally and then configure Jenkins job in the same way

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by test it locally. I have tested it locally and it works locally. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: have you parametrized your configuration? can it be configured outside source code?